# PM2 don't restart on clean exit

Tags: node.js, pm2

PM2 has an option to restart an app on error or clean exit. Unfortunately, even clean zero-code exit increases `restarts` counter. Is there a way to increase `restarts` counter only on error or crash (non-zero code exit)?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that last week in some experimenting with PM2 as I look to use it in production this summer. I was NOT able to find a way to have it discern between restart types. The only thing I found was how to reset the restart counter for an app (along with other meta data for the application), like so:

```
$ pm2 reset <app id>
```